# Leetcode proof of 2160. Minimum Sum of Four Digit Number After Splitting Digits

Tags: proof-writing, algorithms, computer-science

I was trying to study why the solution of [Minimum Sum of Four Digit Number After Splitting Digits](https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-sum-of-four-digit-number-after-splitting-digits/), which is listed under the greedy algorithm.

The problem is essentially taking a number of 4 digits $$x_3 x_2 x_1 x_0 = \sum_{j=0}^3 x_j 10^j$$

Divide the digits into two subsets, so effectively generating two new numbers adding them up and obtaing the minimum sum.

The way I formalized the problem is through the following model

$$
\min_{0 \leq k \leq 3, \sigma \in P_4} \left\{\sum_{j=0}^{k} x_{\sigma(j)} 10^j + \sum_{j=0}^{2-k} x_{\sigma(j+k+1)} 10^j \right\}
$$

Here $k + 1$ is supposed the model the number of digits given to the first number and $P_4$ is the set of all possible permutations.

The solution given at the end is essentially taking the permutation the sorts the digits and use the following formula:

$$
\left( x_{\sigma(3)} + x_{\sigma(2)} \right)10 + \left(x_{\sigma(1)} + x_{\sigma(0)} \right)
$$

Can anyone explain why is the solution the right one? I've tried to prove it in several ways but I can't manage.

Comment: Your latex in the final formula was broken. I attempted to fix it, but you should check that I got the formula right.

Comment: Intuitively, you want large digits to not be multiplied by 10. If anything is going to be multiplied by 10, it should be the smallest digits. And you certainly don't want any digits to be multiplied by 100 (disaster!).

Comment: @littleO yes it's the right formula. As I said $\sigma$ the *sorting permutation*, specifically $\sigma(3)$ is the position of the smallest digit and $\sigma(0)$ is the largest one. I think I understand the intuition but I'd like a formula proof of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Lemma**

If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are digits (integers) such that $ 0 \leq \alpha \leq \beta \leq 9 $ and $p$ and $q$ are non-negative integers such that $p<q$, then:

$$ \beta 10^p + \alpha 10^q \leq \alpha 10^p + \beta 10^q $$

**Proof of lemma**

Let $ \gamma = \beta - \alpha $

Note: $\gamma\geq0$

We have:

$p<q$

$\implies 10^p < 10^q$

$\implies \gamma 10^p \leq \gamma 10^q$ (because $\gamma$ can be $0$)

$\implies \gamma 10^p + \alpha 10^p + \alpha 10^q \leq \gamma 10^q + \alpha 10^p + \alpha 10^q $

$\implies (\gamma + \alpha) 10^p + \alpha 10^q \leq (\gamma + \alpha) 10^q + \alpha 10^p $

$\implies \beta 10^p + \alpha 10^q \leq \beta 10^q + \alpha 10^p $ as required

**Solution to the original problem**

The lemma can be summarised as "assign lower indices to larger digits".

Suppose $a,b,c,d$ are our digits. Without loss of generality, we have $ 0 \leq a \leq b \leq c \leq d \leq 9 $.

Our goal is to assign the indices $A,B,C,D\in\{0,1,2,3\}$ such that no three of these are the same (we only have two available 'digit slots' for each order of magnitude, since in the end we are to return two numbers), in order to minimise the sum $S(A,B,C,D)=a10^A+b10^B+c10^C+d10^D$.

By the above lemma, at least one of the solutions must have $A \geq B \geq C \geq D$. (This part can be proved by contradiction.)

Finally:

Suppose $S(A',B',C',D')$ is one solution.

- A solution must have $D=0$, because $S(A',B',C',0) \leq S(A',B',C',D')$.
- A solution must have $C=0$, because $S(A',B',0,0) \leq S(A',B',C',0)$.
- A solution must have $B=1$, because $S(A',1,0,0) \leq S(A',B',1,0)$. $B=0$ is not allowed for a solution with $D=C=0$, and by this reasoning $B'\neq0$.
- A solution must have $A=1$, because $S(1,1,0,0) \leq S(A',1,1,0)$. $A=0$ is not allowed for a solution with $D=C=0$, and by this reasoning $A'\neq0$.

So $S(1,1,0,0)=10a+10b+c+d$ is a solution.

Comment: Please let me know if you would like me to expand on any part of the proof!

Comment: Hi, I need to read through the full proof. I've used the same lemma as yours but proceeded in two step. In the first step I calculate the min sum with 3 digits and 1 digit for the numbers (by using the lemma and another proposition proved by contradiction). In the second step I've proved the proposition for two digits for each number, and then I took the min. One note, the lemma doesn't require the numbers to be less or equal than 9 (only to be positives).

Comment: @user8469759

Suppose 100a+10b+c+d is your minimum sum with a 3-digit-number and 1-digit-number combination. Then we immediately have 10a+10b+c+d≤100a+10b+c+d. This is why a pair of 2-digit-numbers is optimal.

This idea corresponds to S(1,1,0,0)≤S(2,1,0,0) in the notation used in the proof.

In fact, I think the lemma can work with any real α and β, provided that α≤β (this is the only property used in the proof). Right? I might be missing something.